# Leaf node with encodedPath containing only Hex-Prefix in Merkle Patricia Trie

Tags: go-ethereum, merkle-patricia-tries, state-trie, hex

A leaf node is defined as the tuple [encodedPath, value], and encodedPath uses the Hex-Prefix encoding. Is it possible we have a leaf node with encodedPath having only the prefix and no partial path included?

Taking the following data...

```
<5e 52> : 'val1'
<ac 40> : 'val2'
<ac 4f> : 'val3'
```

...would the trie look like this or I am wrong?

```
rootHash: [ <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, hashA, <>, <>, <>, <>, hashB, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <> ]
hashA:    [ <3e 52>, 'val1' ]
hashB:    [ <00 c4>, hashC ]
hashC:    [ hashD, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, <>, hashE, <> ]
hashD:    [ <20>, 'val2' ]
hashE:    [ <20>, 'val3' ]
```

Note that `rootHash` and `hashC` are branch nodes; `hashB` is an extension node; and `hashA`, `hashD` and `hashE` are leaf nodes.
My doubt is related to `hashD` and `hashE` encodedPaths. If I understood it's correct to put `20` as in HP encoding a leaf node with even path length (in these cases 0) should get the prefix `2` and an additional `0` padding nibble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have constructed the trie in the same format as you did (given the information in https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Patricia-Tree) and this lead me to the same result. To answer your question: Yes, if a leaf node contains no furthers nibbles in the partial path you end it with the prefix 20 (2 for even nibbles count in path and 0 for padding, as you wrote) and no further path.

The encoded path will be stored as a bytearray. The algorithm works like this:
given an encoded path *b* as a bytearray:

```
# Python style code
flag = b[0] & 0xF0
nodetype = flag & 0x2
parity = flag & 0x1
partial_path = []

# parity odd?
if parity:
    partial_path.append(b[0] & 0x0F)

# append all other bytes from the encoded path (or do nothing if there is no encoded path)
for item in b[1:]:
    partial_path.append(item)

# extension node
if not nodetype:
    # do stuff ...

# and so on
```

Comment: Nice, so you really think we are right? Do you think this is a real possible situation or the data is manipulated some way to avoid that? I really need to know for sure this stuff. Please, if you find something in the official documentation or good source that could confirm our test let me know. Cheers

Comment: Yes, by definition it must be like that. Look in the yellow paper: https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf as of 06.09.2018 23:34 UTC. Go to Appendix C and check the last sentence before equation 186 and check equation 186 itself. By this definition you know, it's the prefix + every remaining nibble (in the set Y). If the set is empty, only the prefix is left. @EtherswornCanonist